# Change horizontal uicollectionivew width bases on uiLabel text

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a horizontal collection view.
Each cell has a label and an image.

The problem that I am facing is that when label renders data from the server, sometimes the text is too big and overlaps the image because the width of each cell is fixed.

How can I change the width of the collection View view cell according to the data it contains so that the label does not overlap the image?

Answer (score 0):

CollectionView does have a delegate method which returns cell size.

Please inherit `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and implement the following method.

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAt indexPath:  IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
  }
```

You can calculate your label width and return it to the function.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the width of the label text first with the font associated with the text.

```
extension String {
    func size(with font: UIFont) -> CGSize {
        let fontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
        let size = self.size(withAttributes: fontAttribute)
        return size
    }
}
```

Return the calculated width along with collectionView height in `collectionView(_, collectionViewLayout:_, sizeForItemAt)`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    // Note: Margins are spaces around the cell
    // model[indexPath.row].text is the text of label to be shown
    let newWidth = model[indexPath.row].text.size(with: labelFont!).width + margins + imageView.width 
    return CGSize(width: newWidth, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
}
```

**Note:**

Don't forgot to confirm your viewController to `UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.